# C# Set GlobalHotKey and after pressing it : it compares the text in Clipboard and sets it to something different

Tags: c#, winforms, clipboard

I am trying to make a **background running "app"** which when a **hotkey is pressed** (for example Num0) compares **the inbox of the ClipBoard**(CTRL+C), searches a pre-set collection of data **and sets the value of the clipboard to something different**(after you press CTRL+V something different comes out). Please help me with the **implementation of the GLOBALHOTKEY**. Method used for inserting the data into clipboard is ClipBoard.SetText("New Clipboard");

Comment: Have a look at *GitHub* repository [GlobalHotKey](https://github.com/kyrylomyr/GlobalHotKey).

Comment: You can use [RegisterHotKey()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey).  The drawback here is that if your desired combination is already taken, then the register will fail.

Comment: An alternative would be to use a low level keyboard hook via [WH_KEYBOARD_LL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-hooks).  Examples abound here in SO and out in the internet.